# Find next true in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have to find a function `g : [Bool] -> Integer` such that `g` gives lowest ubication where `True` is in a list of booleans. For example,

> ```
> g [False , False , False , False , True , False , True] ==> 5
> g [False , True , True , False , False] ==> 2
> g [] ==> ***Exception: empty list
> g [False , False] ==> ***Exception: There is no True in your list
> ```

I am not too interested in cases where the function takes `[]` or a list where there is no `True` because I am working on a program where the boolean list is infinite and it's proved that there always exist True. I think a beginning of the definition of the following:

> ```
> g :: [Bool] -> Integer
> g xs | xs == [] = error "empty list"
>      | not (and xs) = error "There is no True in your list"
>      | otherwise = ...
> ```

Can you help me to find `...`, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your second guard look wrong to me, if I understand your requirements properly. Moreover, I don't think you can rule out this case from the start, your function has to just run forever anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is using [`findIndex :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:findIndex):

```
import Data.List(findIndex)
import Data.Maybe(fromJust)

g = fromJust . findIndex id
```

Here you thus use `id` as "predicate" such that `True` is accepted and `False` fails the test. Since in your question you state you know such element always exists, you can use `fromJust` to "*chomp of the `Just`*" so to speak.

In your examples you seem to use "1-indexed" lists, in that case you can define:

```
-- 1-indexed
import Data.List(findIndex)
import Data.Maybe(fromJust)

g = (1+) . fromJust . findIndex id
```

In `ghci`:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List> let g = (1+) . fromJust . findIndex id
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List> g [False , False , False , False , True , False , True]
5
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List> g [False , True , True , False , False]
2
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List> g []
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.List> g [False,False]
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing
```

A final note: it should be:

```
     | not (or xs) = error "There is no True in your list"
```

and not

```
     | not (and xs) = error "There is no True in your list"
```

since `and` is only `True` if **all** elements are `True`.

Comment: But haskell gives me an error when I define `g`: Not in scope `fromJust` and also with `findIndex`.

Comment: @joseabp91: you should `import Data.List` and `import Data.Maybe`.

Comment: I have written `import Data.List` and `import Data.Maybe` but why `g` doesn't take any argument in your definition?

Comment: because of *eta-reduction*.

Comment: @joseabp91: `f x = g (h x)` is equivalent to: `f = g . h`,

Comment: I know but my error is very strange:
>     Couldn't match expected type `a -> Maybe a1'
>           against inferred type `Maybe Int'
>    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `findIndex id xs'
>    In the expression: fromJust . findIndex id xs
>    In the definition of `g':
>        g xs = fromJust . findIndex xs

Comment: Is there any more elementary way?

Comment: @joseabp91: this is not strange, if you feed the argument explicitly, you either have to use brackets or `$`: `g xs = fromJust (findIndex xs)` or `g xs = fromJust $ findIndex xs`.

Comment: @joseabp91: actually using the dots is in my opinion a more elementary way.

Comment: My program still does not work. I'll keep trying, thank you very much

Comment: @joseabp91: in case you want 1-indexed results, the answer is `g xs = (1+) $ fromJust $ findIndex id xs`. Sorry I forgot (well you forgot) the `id`.

Comment: I asked this by this questio I have created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013519/luhn-algorithm-in-haskell

Answer (score 3):

another approach, without error handling

```
> fst . head . filter snd . zip [1..]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd think that

```
(1+) . length . takeWhile not
```

should do that. You can leave out the `(1+)` if you go for 0 based indexes, that is, indexes that would work with `(!!)`